# Date compare:redirect to page based on what date and time. This is not working

Tags: php

I was given the following dates:

```
$startdate = '09/16/2016 07:00:00 AM';
$enddate = '10/14/2016 11:59:59 PM';
```

and I was told that if current date is between those dates, users will be redirected to a page called vote.php where they areable to log in to system and cast a vote.

If however, current date is not within those dates, redirect user to a page called done.php which tells them the voting is over.

I have been trying the following code:

```
$now = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A");
echo $now;
$startdate = '09/16/2016 07:00:00 AM';
$enddate = '10/14/2016 11:59:59 PM';

if ($now < strtotime($startdate) && $now > strtotime($enddate)) {
    header('location:done.php');
    exit;
        header('location:vote.php');
}
```

But I kept getting redirect to a page where users are supposed to continue voting.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I can see error on your code as

```
header('location:vote.php');
```

never going to run coz exit is called before that line.

My approach to this problem is, using three timestamp instead of date. lets have those variables,

```
$startDate= mktime(7,0,0,9,16,2016);
$endDate=   mktime(23,59,59,10,14,2016);

$now=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

if ($now > $startDate && $now < $endDate) {
    header('location:vote.php');
}
else{
    header('location:done.php');
}
```

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() returns a timestamp (an integer count of seconds since [the epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), which you're comparing to a formatted date string (returned by date()).  Apples and oranges.

Instead use:

```
if( time() > strtotime(...
```

...which compares one timestamp (returned by time()) to another (returned by strtotime()).